# First argument must be of type string or an instance of buffer or uint8array. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I made this code and after everything I try it keeps giving me this error.

```
First argument must be of type string or an instance of buffer or uint8array. Received undefined
```

Excuse me for being new at Node.js, but I really don't know where I went wrong. I thank you for your help.

```js
function createServer(obj){
  var i;
  obj.port = (obj.port || 8080);
  obj.path = (obj.path || "/");

  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    for(i in obj.path){
      fs.readFile(i, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      })
    }
    
  }).listen(obj.port);

  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing this?  Is it the `fs.readFile`?  What is `obj`?  Can you provide sample input?

Comment: Alright the full project is here [https://github.com/notJudahRR/Firwe](https://github.com/notJudahRR/Firwe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index.js file [https://github.com/notJudahRR/Firwe/blob/main/index.js] set path as an object:

```
const firwe = require("./src/index.js");

let server = firwe({
  port: 8080,
  path: {
    "/": "index.html"
  },
});
server.initServer();
```

Then, in server.js [https://github.com/notJudahRR/Firwe/blob/main/src/server.js] you must handle appropriately:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const type = require("./type.js");

function createServer(obj) {
  var i;
  obj.port = obj.port || 8080;
  obj.path = obj.path || {
    "/": "index.html",
  };

  http
    .createServer((req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      Object.values(obj.path).forEach((v) => {
        fs.readFile(v, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          res.write(data);
          res.end();
        });
      });
    })
    .listen(obj.port);

  return obj;
}

module.exports = createServer;
```

Object.values loop in each object property value and then you get the **index.html** to get the file to render.